# Matplotlib subplot object being classified/recoqnized as numpy array. Hence not able to use twinx() function and etc

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I'm trying to plot two plots on the same graph, one Y axis on either sides sharing the same X axis. I've done this earlier and hence knew how to do it *(or I though so)*. Anyways now I was trying to implement it under a function since I need to make a lot of plots and hence wanted a more modular solution.
Now when trying to run the same thing under a fucntion it throws error **'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'**. This is because for some reason ax1 is being shown of class **numpy.ndarray** which should actually be **matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot**.

Please Help.

```py
    def pumped_up_plotting(data, colname1, colname2):
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(13, 4, figsize=(5*4, 5*13))
        print("Look here lil bitch: ", type(ax1))
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

        for i in range(0, 13):
            for j in range(0,4):
                id_ = profiles[i*4+j]
                samp = data[data["profile_id"] == id_]

                ax1[i, j].plot(samp["time"], samp[colname1], label=colname1, color="blue")
                ax2[i, j].plot(samp["time"], samp[colname2], label=colname2, color="yellow")
                ax1[i, j].set_xlabel("Time")
            
                lines_1, labels_1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
                lines_2, labels_2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
            
                lines = lines_1 + lines_2
                labels = labels_1 + labels_2

                ax1[i, j].legend(lines, labels, loc=0)

    pumped_up_plotting(df, "rotor", "motor_work")
```

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PO91.png)

Comment: Please don't post images - post text. See [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll make sure of it from next time. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax1` is a numpy array because you are creating a grid of 13 by 4 axes instead of a single axes. You do this by supplying 13 and 4 as the first two arguments to `plt.subplots`. I'm not sure what you intended those numbers to do, but if you delete them, it should work.

As of now, ax1 is a numpy array with 13 columns an 4 rows containing the individual axis objects.

I'll try to explain what went wrong. To simplify, I'm gonna use a 2 x 2 grid instead of 13 x 4. So `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(2, 2)`.

Then, `ax1` will look like this:

```
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)
```

If you try to call `ax1.twinx()`, it won't work because `ax1` is actually not an axis, but the array containing all your 4 axes of the grid.
So what you would have to call if you wanted to create a twin axis of the first axis, would be `ax1[0,0].twinx()`. Since you want to do it for every axis and not just the first one, you can do it inside a nested loop where you loop over the rows and columns of the numpy array. Since you are already doing this, you can justput that line inside your already existing loop.

This looks like that line.
`ax2 = ax1[i, j].twinx()`
Here, we are taking the individual axis object from the numpy array by indexing (as you were already doing before) and calling `twinx` on it. This returns a twin axis which we are saving as `ax2`. Note that this is kind of confusing, since `ax2` is a single axis object while `ax1` is an array containg axis objects. I personally would rename `ax1` to `axs` so it's clear this variable contains multiple axes.

Because `ax2` is already a single axis object, we can call the plotting functions directly on it, and don't have to index it.

```
def pumped_up_plotting(data, colname1, colname2):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(13, 4, figsize=(5*4, 5*13))
    print("Type of ax1 ", type(ax1))
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

    for i in range(0, 13):
        for j in range(0,4):
            ax2 = ax1[i, j].twinx()
            id_ = profiles[i*4+j]
            samp = data[data["profile_id"] == id_]

            ax1[i, j].plot(samp["time"], samp[colname1], label=colname1, color="blue")
            ax2.plot(samp["time"], samp[colname2], label=colname2, color="yellow")
            ax1[i, j].set_xlabel("Time")
        
            lines_1, labels_1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
            lines_2, labels_2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        
            lines = lines_1 + lines_2
            labels = labels_1 + labels_2

            ax1[i, j].legend(lines, labels, loc=0)

pumped_up_plotting(df, "rotor", "motor_work")
```

My way of doing this more clearly would be:

```
def pumped_up_plotting(data, colname1, colname2):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(13, 4, figsize=(5*4, 5*13))   
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

    for i, row in enumerate(axs):
        for j, ax in enumerate(row):
            ax2 = ax.twinx()
            id_ = profiles[i*4+j]
            samp = data[data["profile_id"] == id_]

            ax.plot(samp["time"], samp[colname1], label=colname1, color="blue")
            ax2.plot(samp["time"], samp[colname2], label=colname2, color="yellow")
            ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        
            lines_1, labels_1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
            lines_2, labels_2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        
            lines = lines_1 + lines_2
            labels = labels_1 + labels_2

            ax.legend(lines, labels, loc=0)

pumped_up_plotting(df, "rotor", "motor_work")
```

Comment: I did those to make a 13 x 4 grid, since i needed 52 plots.
Removing the 13,4 solved the type problem (thank you), but I'm still not able to make the plots.
It says **TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable**.

Comment: Yeah well then you get back a numpy array that contains the axes. Then you have to access the individual axes by indexing or looping over the array.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand what you mean to say. But to clarify I have been using two for loops to do that.

Comment: Try the code in my edit.

Comment: Your provided code worked. Thank you so much. I see what edit you've made and slightly understood where I went wrong. Thanks a lot. If you can spare a few minutes can you once explain what was exactly wrong in my approach and how did you figure out to solve it, since python still tells me that ax1 is numpy array but plots are now here.

Once again thanks a lot. This solved my problem.

Comment: I have tried to explain it in another edit.